# Is there a way to detect black on FFMPEG video files

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I am trying to run a QC check on my video files.

I know that there is a way to detect black frame or audio loss in a video file. Can anyone help me with how the syntax is written?

I have tried doing the following but I am having issues as I do not know how to tell from the output.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mxf -vf blackdetect=d=0.1:pix_th=.1 -f rawvideo -y /dev/null
```

Also is there ay ways to check if I have any packets that are in error by using `ffprobe` or `ffmpeg`

I also do not understand waht this `0.1:pix_th=.1` is doing?

EDIT*:

I have used this command now

```
ffmpeg -i 01.mxf -vf blackdetect=d=0:pix_th=.01 -f rawvideo -y /NUL
```

this gives me

> [blackdetect @ 000001a2ed843740] black_start:0.04 black_end:2
>
> black_duration:1.96
>
> [mpeg2video @ 000001a2ed86efc0] ac-tex damaged at 45 304.08
>
> bitrate=829328.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed= 5.6x

However, the actual video has more than this for the black frame.

is there a way to tell it to continue looking at the video and get all black frames, not just the first instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also do not understand what this 0.1:pix_th=.1 is doing?

1. **d=0.1** mention the duration of continues black screen in seconds which you wants to detect. For example, if you set it as 5 then you ll get notified only if the input video contains black screen for 5 or more seconds. It won't detect less than 5 second black.
2. **pix_th=.1** mention the pixel threshold of black frame which you want to detect (darkness of the black frame). 
   You can set a value between 0 to 1.

   0-> pure black (maximum dark).

   1-> lite black (detect all frames, because you are telling the ffmpeg to detect minimum to maximum pixel value as black frame).

> However, the actual video has more than this for the black frame.
>
> is there a way to tell it to continue looking at the video and get all black frames, not just the first instance.

Increase the **pix_th** value and check.

for more information [BlackDetect](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#blackdetect)